# How to send more than 2083 characters of data to a URL?

Tags: url

Lets say I have a list of 1500 integers, about 15 characters each. So a list of about 22500 characters. How would I send this to my web service so I can query my database with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs have two limitations:

- Length (which may vary by web server, but is always limited)
- Structure (fine for simple key/value pairs, for the most part, but not useful beyond that)

If you're looking to send a fairly significant amount of structured data to the server, a [POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) is what you're looking for.  The request can carry a simple list of key/value pairs separate from the URL, but can also carry a request *body* (GET requests can not), which is a great place to store structured data (perhaps in JSON format, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use POST instead of GET